# Removing folders older than 5 days

Tags: command-line, directory, delete, find, rm

I have a backup folder than uses a calendar like folder structure to organise files. I want to delete these every 5 days but I end up deleting the full backup because the main folder is older than 5 days.

Folder structure:

```
Backup
    -> 2017
          -> October
                 -> 28
                 -> 29
                 -> 30
                 -> 31
          -> November
                 -> 1
                 -> 2
                 -> 3
```

I've tried running this command:

```
find /mnt/backup/* -type d -mtime +5 -execdir rm -rf {} \;
```

But it will remove the directory 2017 because it is older than 5 days, which in turn means it will remove all the subfolders. I only want to delete directories inside here that are 5 days old. For example if today was November 3rd I only want to have the directories 28 and 29 to delete. Then when it becomes 5th November I want the full October directory to be deleted as everything in there will now be older than 5 days. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Use `-mindepth 1` so that `find` always only checks subdirectories of 2017? Also, `find` has a `-delete` action you can use instead of `-execdir rm -rf ...`

Comment: Maybe I've missed something, but is there a reason why you can't specify the 2017 directory in the original find request? I.e. `find /mnt/backup/2017/*` instead of `find /mnt/backup/*`

Comment: What happens then when 2017 turns to 2018? Will I have to manually come along then and delete 2017? - That's the reason @ThePizzaOverlord

Comment: @Stuart - thought that may have been the case. In the example I gave, yeah, but like most people seem to be agreeing on, you can just use `-mindepth 1` to skip over ANY subdirectory on the same 'level' (aka depth)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `-mindepth 1` if you don't want `2017` to  be touched:

```
$ mkdir -p foo/2017/{October/{28..31},November/{1..3}}
$ touch -d 'now - 6 days' foo/2017/October/{28,29} foo/2017
$ find foo/* -mindepth 1 -mtime +5
foo/2017/October/28
foo/2017/October/29
$ find foo/* -mtime +5
foo/2017
foo/2017/October/28
foo/2017/October/29
```

If you start from `foo` instead of `foo/2017`, then use `-mindepth 2`:

```
$ find foo/ -mindepth 2 -mtime +5
foo/2017/October/28
foo/2017/October/29
```